# I have a faulty Ajax call apparently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a project where a user can have his own VirtualDiary online. He/She registers logs in and all that and is brought to a entry page with the date and a text area. The idea is that they will be able to click on two buttons on the top of the page titled `NextPage` and `PreviousPage`. These will call a jquery ajax function which will in turn change the value of `EntryID + 1` or `EntryID -1`. This should change the value of pretty much everything on the page. But nothing happens even though the ajax call logs success. I am very new to ajax so I have probably Done something really stupid. Thanks in advance

PHP

```
<?php 
 session_start();

 //error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_WARNING);
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cannot");
 mysql_select_db("virtualdiary") or die ("db");

$JoinDateQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UID = '".$_SESSION['UID']."' ");

if($JoinDateQuery === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($JoinDateQuery))
{
$JoinDate =  $row[4];
}


 $TodayDate = date("Y/m/d");
 $today = strtotime($TodayDate);
 $joinTime = strtotime($JoinDate);
 $datediff = $today - $joinTime;
 $_SESSION["EntryID"] = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
 $EntryID = $_SESSION["EntryID"];
 $_SESSION['EntryDate'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($JoinDate. ' + '.$EntryID .'days'));
 $EntryDate = $_SESSION['EntryDate'];


$id = $_SESSION["UID"] ;








if (isset($_POST["entry"])){
$entry = $_POST["entry"];

$deletion = "DELETE FROM entries WHERE UserID = '".$_SESSION['UID']."' and EntryID = '".$EntryID."' ";
mysql_query($deletion);
$submission = "INSERT INTO `virtualdiary`.`entries` (`Entry`, `UserID`,`EntryID`) VALUES ('". $entry . "',                    '".$_SESSION['UID']."', '".$EntryID."')";
mysql_query($submission);


}
$ThePost = 'SELECT * FROM entries WHERE UserID = "'.   $_SESSION['UID'] .'" and EntryID = "'.$EntryID.'"';
$result = mysql_query($ThePost);

if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error());
}




 ?>

<html>

 <head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Entry.css"/>
 <title>Home</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#NextDay').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "Home.php",
 data: "$EntryID = $EntryID + 1",
success: console.log("success")     

}); //ajax call
 });//on click next day
 });//document ready</script>

</head>
<body>
<section>
<button id="previousDay" class="day">Previous Day</button>
<button class = "day" id = "date">Joined: <?php echo $JoinDate; ?></br>
                 Entry Number: <?php echo $EntryID + 1; ?></br>
                 EntryDate: <?php echo $EntryDate ; ?>
                 </button>
<button class="day" id = "NextDay">Next Day</button>
<h1>Entry:  </h1>
<form method="post" action="Home.php">
<textarea name="entry" rows="24" cols="80">
<?php 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['Entry'];
}
?>
</textarea>
 </br>
 </br>
 <input name="submit" type="submit"/>    
 </form>

<a href="Calender.php"> <button id="calender" class = "day"><h1>Calender</h1></button></a>

 <button id="LogOut"><a href="LogOut.php">Log Out</a></button>
 </section>
 </body>

 </html>
```

By the way `EntryID` returns result of 4 (or the default for the user on this day) so its pretty obvious the problem has something to do with the `Data:` part of the ajax or that I am not using ajax in the right context to achieve what I want.

EDIT: I have just been made aware that `$EntryID = $EntryID + 1` has to be defined somewhere but where and I can't just plonk it down somewhere cause that would change the first instance of entry id I think.

Comment: `data: "$EntryID = EntryID + 1",` EntryID is not defined anywhere.

Comment: oh I see what you mean but where should I define it

Comment: I'm not even sure what you expect `"$EntryID = EntryID + 1"` to *do*.  That's just a string being passed to the server, and it's not formatted like any kind of key/value pair one would normally see in an HTTP request.  When you inspect the AJAX request in your browser debugging tools, is that entire string even sent to the server at all?  How does the server-side code read and interpret it?  There's no key by which to identify it, so it can't be pulled from `$_GET[]`, can it?  And even if it can, does the server-side code then *evaluate* the expression?  That's *really* dangerous.

Comment: If you thought you could mix JavaScript and PHP together with no issues then you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you should be making an AJAX "POST" request, not a "GET" request. (Just industry standard, since you're sending a value through to a server).

Second, I'm not sure, where you got the syntax to create a data value for that GET request (really weird) however!, in the ajax call where I edited your code, there should now be the correct way of creating & sending de-serializable data.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention, that the values sent from the AJAX, can be retrieved using `$_REQUEST['xyx']` or `$_POST['xyz']`.. If you are using get, you can use `$_GET['xyz']`

**UNTESTED**

```
//error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_WARNING);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("cannot");
mysql_select_db("virtualdiary") or die ("db");

$JoinDateQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UID = '" . $_SESSION['UID'] . "' ");

if ($JoinDateQuery === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($JoinDateQuery)) {
    $JoinDate = $row[4];
}


$TodayDate = date("Y/m/d");
$today = strtotime($TodayDate);
$joinTime = strtotime($JoinDate);
$datediff = $today - $joinTime;
$_SESSION["EntryID"] = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
$EntryID = $_POST["EntryID"];
$_SESSION['EntryDate'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($JoinDate . ' + ' . $EntryID . 'days'));
$EntryDate = $_SESSION['EntryDate'];


$id = $_SESSION["UID"];


if (isset($_POST["entry"])) {
    $entry = $_POST["entry"];

    $deletion = "DELETE FROM entries WHERE UserID = '" . $_SESSION['UID'] . "' and EntryID = '" . $EntryID . "' ";
    mysql_query($deletion);
    $submission = "INSERT INTO `virtualdiary`.`entries` (`Entry`, `UserID`,`EntryID`) VALUES ('" . $entry . "',                    '" . $_SESSION['UID'] . "', '" . $EntryID . "')";
    mysql_query($submission);


}
$ThePost = 'SELECT * FROM entries WHERE UserID = "' . $_SESSION['UID'] . '" and EntryID = "' . $EntryID . '"';
$result = mysql_query($ThePost);

if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
}




?>

<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Entry.css"/>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#NextDay').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home.php",
                    data: {
                        EntryID: '1' //not sure (this is quite conditional I guess)
                    },
                    success: console.log("success")

                }); //ajax call
            });//on click next day
        });//document ready</script>

</head>
<body>
<section>
    <button id="previousDay" class="day">Previous Day</button>
    <button class="day" id="date">Joined: <?php echo $JoinDate; ?></br>
        Entry Number: <?php echo $EntryID + 1; ?></br>
        EntryDate: <?php echo $EntryDate; ?>
    </button>
    <button class="day" id="NextDay">Next Day</button>
    <h1>Entry: </h1>

    <form method="post" action="Home.php">
        <textarea name="entry" rows="24" cols="80">
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['Entry'];
            }
            ?>
        </textarea>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <a href="Calender.php">
        <button id="calender" class="day"><h1>Calender</h1></button>
    </a>

    <button id="LogOut"><a href="LogOut.php">Log Out</a></button>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesnt work even though it still returns success. Should it change the url I am not to sure on this at all sorry. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Sorry didnt see yOur edit so should it be `$_POST['EntryID]`OR `$_POST["$EntryID"]`

Comment: Yip.. well try it at least.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure when the values should be posted, or what values should be posted.. However, you were correct in your ajax `data` field being faulty. Also, not sure what your server side logic is, so didn't really want to edit anything there, but you retrieve the values using `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` super globals.

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

data
Type: PlainObject or String
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

You're trying to happened "$EntryID = EntryID + 1" to "home.php"

"home.php$EntryID = EntryID + 1" doesn't seem like a correct url ?

You should try with the error callback set if you want more informations on the request status.

Comment: it is supposed to be `$EntryID = $EntryID + 1`

Comment: I am struggling to understand but could it possibly mean the url should become something like `$EntryID + 1`??????